# SSO login fails from ESB while authenticating from WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

While im trying to login from wso2esb ,i have enabled sso at that point .So it takes me to wso2 is page . While authenticating from WSO2 IS. login fails. resulting in an error logs as :

```
2015-06-18 07:54:22,403 log_level=ERROR thread=http-nio-9443-exec-40 logger=org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.IdentityProviderManager [Could not find Resident Identity Provider for tenant carbon.super]
2015-06-18 07:54:22,403 log_level=ERROR thread=http-nio-9443-exec-40 logger=org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor [Error processing the authentication request]
org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException: Error occurred while retrieving Resident Identity Provider information for tenant carbon.super
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil.getIssuer(SAMLSSOUtil.java:420)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.builders.DefaultResponseBuilder.buildResponse(DefaultResponseBuilder.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor.process(SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor.java:153)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.SAMLSSOService.authenticate(SAMLSSOService.java:140)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleAuthenticationReponseFromFramework(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:670)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequest(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:177)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.doGet(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:93)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-06-18 07:54:22,406 log_level=ERROR thread=http-nio-9443-exec-40 logger=org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.IdentityProviderManager [Could not find Resident Identity Provider for tenant carbon.super]
2015-06-18 07:54:22,406 log_level=ERROR thread=http-nio-9443-exec-40 logger=org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet [Error when processing the authentication request!]
org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException: Error when authenticating the users
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.SAMLSSOService.authenticate(SAMLSSOService.java:142)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleAuthenticationReponseFromFramework(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:670)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequest(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:177)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.doGet(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:93)
```

Let me know what is missing here .

Comment: What is your identity server & ESB version?

Comment: Identity Server is 5.0.0 and ESB is 4.8.0

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the below.
1. Have you registered ESB as SP?
2. Have you enabled SAML2SSOAuthenticator and configured ServiceProviderID in /repository/conf/security/authenticators.xml
3. Have you given the correct assertion consumer url with the correct port?
E.g., https://localhost:9445/acs

Please make sure your steps as given in [1].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Enabling+SSO+for+WSO2+Servers